# How to write a sparse Linux (EXT4) disk image without writing gigabytes of zeros?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, disk-image

I have a 64 GB Linux disk image with ~50 GB of unused space across the partitions. The file is sparse, so it only takes ~14 GB on disk.

But if I `dd` the image, it writes the full 64 GB, which takes quite a while.

Is there any way I can do the equivalent of `dd if=os.img of=/dev/sdb` with this image, without having to write 50 GB of zeros?

Is there any tool that is smart enough to do this i.e. an imaging tool that has an awareness of the EXT4 filesystem?

Comment: In general, not writing sparse blocks as zeros to the disk can produce errors: The zeros in sparse regions of `os.img` can be important. For example, a filesystem that uses a bitmap to keep track of free blocks may have a full bock of zero bytes in this bitmap. This block of zero bytes must go onto the disk. If the disk has other data from previous use in this location and the block is skipped when writing as it is sparse in `os.img`, the filesystem will be inconsistent and may use some blocks twice, for different files.

Answer (score 7):

`dd` can handle this. You need to add `conv=sparse` to the command line.

From the man page:

```
              try to seek rather than write the output for NUL input blocks
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I did consider `conv=sparse` but don't think it works in this case. I could be wrong.

When dd is creating a file inside a filesystem it can safely seek because EXT4 supports sparse files (i.e. it will treat that seeked-over space as zeros).

But when it's writing to a disk device, it's going to seek over random parts of the disk device which could be zeros or junk data, causing corruption.

It seems like I would have to `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/device` first to ensure I have all zeros, which would defeat the purpose.

Seems like an FS-aware tool is req.

Comment: @hackerattacker2019 What are you writing the image to?

Comment: I'm writing the image to a block device (an SSD) e.g. `/dev/sdb`

Comment: If it's really an SSD then it doesn't matter because you'll have trimmed the device first.

Comment: I am zeroing the drive with ATA security erase, it does read all zeros in my tests. So this does seem like it should work but I'm slightly uneasy ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would consider using `mksquashfs` to create a read-only copy instead of making a `dd` of whole volume. This additionally compresses and de-duplicates the data.

Please note that you have to evaluate - it's usability depends on your specific use case.

Answer (score 3):

It is awkward since you have a whole disk image but you could:

1. use your partitioning program of choice to list the partitions in `os.img` and create them on `/dev/sdb`
2. restore each partition with e2image. e.g., `e2image -aro 1048576 os.img /dev/sdb1`

This does not handle the MBR if there is one. `/bin/dd if=os.img of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1` will do that.

Note: the e2image man page at linux.die.net is out of date. From a bionic install:

```
SYNOPSIS
   e2image [ -r|Q ] [ -f ] device image-file
   e2image -I device image-file
   e2image -ra [ -cfnp ] [ -o src_offset ] [ -O dest_offset ] src_fs [ dest_fs ]
```

Comment: The `e2image` utility does seem like exactly what I'm looking for. Will have to give this a try. Thank you!

Comment: This is the answer that should be accepted. And because `e2image` is filesystem aware it won't copy non-zero-filled free blocks, unlike some other tools like `ddrescue`

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Use `partclone`.

Skipping the sparse blocks is only a good idea if either you can be sure that the disk is filled with zero bytes, e.g. because you just wiped it, or if you know that `os.img` only has sparse blocks (holes) where the contents do not matter. The latter is not easy to know. An essential block of zero bytes can, for example, come from a filesystem that stores a non-sparse file containing a block of zero bytes. The file `os.img` may have a hole at this block from copying, running a tool such as `fallocate --dig-holes` to save space, or automatic de-duplication where the de-duplication source is an existing sparse file.

More likely, you want to write the blocks that are relevant to the filesystem(s) in `os.img` and only these blocks. You can do this with `partclone`.

- If `os.img` has a single filesystem you can directly use it as a source, pipe the partclone backup to a restore process that writes to the disk partition. (`partclone` has an option `--dev-to-dev` but the man page does not clarify whether this skips unused blocks.)
- If there are partitions on `os.img`, you can use `losetup --find --show --partscan os.img` to access them and then use `partclone` on each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bmaptool](https://github.com/intel/bmap-tools) for exactly that purpose. `bmaptool` has a few advantages over `dd`, see their web page. You run it in two steps:

1. Create the bmap from the file; the bmap lists blocks which are occupied.
2. Write the file using the generated bmap.

```sh
# Create bmap
bmaptool create -o os.img.bmap os.img

# Burn to disk (equivalent to dd if=os.img of=/dev/sdb)
bmaptool copy --bmap os.img.bmap /dev/sdb
```

I am using this right now with a HD dump taken with `ddrescue -S` (which creates a sparse dump). The dump is 230 GB, but as sparse file it only uses 23 GB, and `bmaptool` writes the dump in a bit more than one minute.